# CSS causing Visual Studio 2015 Preview to crash

Tags: css, visual-studio-2015

I believe there used to be a similar .min file related issue in VS but that was fixed long time ago.

So following is the new CSS I've added and since then, every time I hit space bar to insert a new class in my html tags, it fails to load CSS list and crashes.

My CSS snippet is

```
/* ANIMATIONS */

/* spin animation*/
.glyphicon-spin-animate {    
    animation: spin .6s infinite linear;
    -webkit-animation: spin .6s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin .6s infinite linear;
}

@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    to { -moz-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    to { -webkit-transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform:scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    to { transform: scale(1) rotate(360deg);}
}


.alert-info.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 0.7s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInDown 0.7s;

  animation: fadeInDown 0.7s;
}

.alert-success.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadeInDown 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInDown 2s;

  animation: fadeInDown 2s;
}

.alert-danger.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: shake 1s;
  -moz-animation: shake 1s;

  animation: shake 1s;
}


.alert-info.ng-leave, .alert-success.ng-leave, .alert-danger.ng-leave{
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutUp 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutUp 1s;

  animation: fadeOutUp 1s;
}

.item-row.ng-enter, .item-exra-row.ng-enter{
  -webkit-animation: fadeInLeft 0.7s;
  -moz-animation: fadeInLeft 0.7s; 
  animation: fadeInLeft 0.7s;
}

.item-row.ng-leave , .item-exra-row.ng-leave{
  -webkit-animation: fadeOutLeft 0.7s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOutLeft 0.7s;  
  animation: fadeOutLeft 0.7s;
}
```

Can someone please point what is wrong in above CSS?

Thanks.

PS: Animations are defined in [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

Comment: In case someone is interested, I got rid of the crash by removing /**/ comments. Weird though!

Answer (score 1):

my colleagues tell me this is a known problem with an earlier release of Web Essentials 2015, which is fixed in the [latest release](http://vswebessentials.com/download).

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem:
when changing @keyframes in css file my Visual Studio Community 2013 crashes every 2nd, 3rd time.

I tried updating Web Essentials 2015 to .5 .. did not helped

I noticed that almost invisible icon of VS2013 on my Firefox, I disabled that 'Enable Browser Link' in VS2013 and it helped. It is near refresh browser button's dropdown menu in VS and uses SignalIR to refresh the page you edited.